# Matrix representation of a non-linear transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I know that the matrix representation of the linear transformation:
$x_1=X_1+2\lambda X_2$
$x_2=X_2 - \lambda X_1$

is:

$  \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   x_1\\
   x_2\\
  \end{array} } \right]=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2\lambda \\
   -\lambda & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   X_1\\
   X_2\\
  \end{array} } \right]$

but what if I have the non-linear transformation:
$x_1=X_1+2\lambda X_2X_1^2$
$x_2=X_2 - \lambda X_1$

How can it be expressed in matrix form to get it's inverse?

**Edit:**

So, if i cannot represent it in matrix form, how can I get the inverse transformation?

Comment: Matrices are for expressing linear transformations. You cannot express something nonlinear in $x$ in the form $Ax$ for any matrix $A$.

Comment: Not quite true. Quadratic forms are not linear and still one can express them using a matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edited the question, I did not know whether to comment or edit it

Comment: What does an inverse transformation have to do with a matrix? An inverse transformation is the way to get back to the origin from an image, linear or not.

Comment: Well, I just know that method to invert the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lambda=0$, the transformation is clearly a bijection (geometrical interpretation : it is a symmetry with respect to the line with equation $y=x$),

For any nonzero value of $\lambda$, this transformation cannot be a bijection because point (0,2) would be the image of 3 different points by the inverse transformation. These points are :

$$\tag{1}(X_1,X_2)=\begin{cases}(0,2)&\ \text{it's a fixed point.}\\
(\frac{1}{\lambda}(-1+a),1+a)&\\
(\frac{1}{\lambda}(-1-a),1-a)&
\end{cases} \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ a:=\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Using other words, your system taken with $x_1=0$ and $x_2=2$, i.e.,:

$$\tag{2}\begin{cases}(i)&...&0&=&X_1+2\lambda X_2X_1^2\\
(ii)&...&2&=&X_2 - \lambda X_1\\
\end{cases}$$

has the 3 solutions given in (1).

$Remarks:$

- The second and third solutions in (1) are easily found by expressing in (2)(ii) $X_2=\lambda X_1+2$ and then plugging this expression into (2)(i), getting a quadratic equation for $X_1$.
- All points $(0,y)$ are fixed points of the transformation.
- There are many cases where, being given $(x_1,x_2)$, there are two solutions for $(X_1,X_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to show mathematically that the transformation is not bijective from a certain $\lambda$ and what $\lambda$ is it, what path can I take? And what path to get the inverse transformation inside the domain where it's bijective?

Comment: I have a definitive answer now : unless $\lambda=0$, it is never bijective (see why in my answer).